# Almacenar vídeos en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo la duda de cual es la manera correcta de guardar vídeos o subirlos, en Django.

El `field` que podría funcionar creo yo, seria un `FileField`, ¿Pero es esta una buena opción u alternativa?

También vi una propuesta por ahí de tener un campo `FilePathField`, teniendo ahí las rutas de los vídeos y acceder así a ellos cuando se necesario, pero no me convence mucho.

Cualquier sugerencia ayuda a mi aprendizaje. De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tu necesitas es un campo de tipo `FileField`, ya el `FilePathField` es como un `CharField` pero con unos métodos extra para encontrar archivos de una manera "fuzzy".
Lo que debes hacer es declarar en tu modelo un campo de tipo `FileField` y en el parámetro `upload_to` colocar la ruta relativa a la carpeta a la cual quieres que se suban tus archivos.
Recuerda tener bien configurado tu archivo `settings.py` con las variables `MEDIA_ROOT` y `MEDIA_URL` ya que los archivos se subirán a la carpeta `MEDIA_ROOT`/ruta_relativa que colocaste en tu modelo.
Mas info aquí [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield).